# Control key plus mouse wheel

Tags: c#, events, mousewheel, keydown

What's the better way to handle the ctrl + mouse wheel in C#?
I've figured out how to handle the MouseWheel event but how to know that the ctrl key is being pressed too?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use the static property like:

```
System.Windows.Forms.Control.ModifierKeys
```