# Control zoom level of WinForms using mouse scroll wheel and Ctrl in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, winforms, scroll, zooming, ctrl

If I have a winform, may I know how can I control the zoom level of the font in the application (as well as the application window itself obviously) by using Ctrl + Mouse Scroll Wheel? I see there is a Delta in the Scroll Wheel event, but not sure how that works. Is there any code sample that I can look into?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to handle the [`KeyDown`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown.aspx) and [`KeyUp`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keyup.aspx) event in order to determine whether or not <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is being held down. This value should be stored at class-level because it will be used by other subroutines besides the `KeyDown` and `KeyUp` events.

You then write code to handle the form's [`MouseWheel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseWheel.aspx) event. Scrolling downwards (towards you) causes a negative value for the [`Delta`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs.delta.aspx) property of the `MouseEventArgs`. Scrolling upwards is obviously the reverse. The value of the Delta property is always currently 120.

Microsoft's reason for this value is as follows:

> Currently, a value of 120 is the standard for one detent. If higher resolution mice are introduced, the definition of WHEEL_DELTA might become smaller. Most applications should check for a positive or negative value rather than an aggregate total.

In your context you'll just check for the sign of the Delta and perform an action.

Here is a sample code implementing basic 'zoom' functionality:

```
Public Class Form1
    Enum ZoomDirection
        None
        Up
        Down
    End Enum

    Dim CtrlIsDown As Boolean
    Dim ZoomValue As Integer

    Sub New()

        ' This call is required by the designer.
        InitializeComponent()

        ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.
        ZoomValue = 100
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_KeyDown_KeyUp(ByVal sender As Object, _
                                    ByVal e As KeyEventArgs) _
                Handles Me.KeyDown, Me.KeyUp

        CtrlIsDown = e.Control
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_MouseWheel(ByVal sender As Object, 
                                 ByVal e As MouseEventArgs) _
                Handles Me.MouseWheel

        'check if control is being held down
        If CtrlIsDown Then
            'evaluate the delta's sign and call the appropriate zoom command
            Select Case Math.Sign(e.Delta)
                Case Is < 0
                    Zoom(ZoomDirection.Down)
                Case Is > 0
                    Zoom(ZoomDirection.Up)
                Case Else
                    Zoom(ZoomDirection.None)
            End Select
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Zoom(ByVal direction As ZoomDirection)
        'change the zoom value based on the direction passed

        Select Case direction
            Case ZoomDirection.Up
                ZoomValue += 1
            Case ZoomDirection.Down
                ZoomValue -= 1
            Case Else
                'do nothing
        End Select

        Me.Text = ZoomValue.ToString()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Read on the following for more information about your question:

1. [MSDN: Control.KeyDown Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keydown.aspx)
2. [MSDN: Control.KeyUp Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keyup.aspx)
3. [MSDN: Control.MouseWheel Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mouseWheel.aspx)
4. [MSDN: MouseEventArgs Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.mouseeventargs.aspx)

Comment: Thanks so much for such detailed answer! This has everything I was looking for!

Comment: Just one problem though...for some reason my code seems to be able to capture the mouse movements but not the key down and key up part unless I use the mouse the click on the form first...is that expected or I am just doing something silly?

Comment: BTW, sorry I do not have enough reputation to vote this answer up yet, I'd have done that if I could!

Comment: @zhuanyi: Sorry I totally forgot about that. Just set the form's `KeyPreview` property to `True`

Comment: Right before   CtrlIsDown = e.Control? Thanks!

Comment: @zhuanyi: You can set that anywhere but preferably, it should be done in the Designer view otherwise do it during the form's initializer (`New()`) or at `Form.Load`.

Answer (score 6):

I suspect that you can just test:

(VB.NET):

```
If (ModifierKeys And Keys.Control) = Keys.Control Then
```

(C#):

```
if( (ModifierKeys  & Keys.Control) == Keys.Control )
```

to check if the control key is down.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/268796/control-key-plus-mouse-wheel

Answer (score -1):

For CrystalReportViewer1

Just put CrystalReportViewer1.Zoom(ZoomValue)
instead of the line  Me.Text = ZoomValue.ToString() in the Sub Zoom

Comment: OP's question was not about CrystalReport. May be it is a good answer, but not to this question.